# Cells are showing their formulae and not the results thereof. How to revert to results?

Tags: excel

I hit a short-cut by mistake and now all of my values are being shown as their formulae.

How do I revert back to seeing the results of the sums and not the formulae?

Answer (score 1):

I think you hit CTRL + `.  Press it again to show the results.  (The accent is the key left of the 1 key).